# Can NPC scouts make a bonus action shortsword attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, attack, npc, two-weapon-fighting

In the game I'm playing, the DM gave each member of the party control over an NPC in combat, in addition to our own characters. My NPC is a [scout](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/17007-scout), so she can use her action to make 2 melee attacks with her shortswords, or 2 ranged attacks with her longbow.

Shortswords have the light property, meaning that if someone takes the Attack action to attack with a shortsword they're holding in one hand, they can use a bonus action to make another attack with a shortsword in their other hand, without adding their ability modifier to the damage of the second attack.

In theory, this NPC should be able to use a bonus action to attack with the shortsword in her off-hand after making 2 melee attacks as her action, but that's not anywhere in the scout stat block. Are the rules different for NPCs? Is the intent that the second attack she gets with her action replaces this?

Comment: Welcome to the stack Jonathan, take the [tour] when you have a moment. I’ve closed this as a duplicate since it has been asked before.